# What's the converse of a subcontractor?

Tags: single-word-requests

My understanding of contractors and clients is something like:

```
Party 1
   |
   V
Party 2
   |
   V
Party 3

Legend:
  "->": "employs"
```

From the perspective of **Party 1**:

- **Party 2** is a contractor
- **Party 3** is a subcontractor

From the perspective of **Party 2**:

- **Party 1** is a client
- **Party 3** is a contractor

From the perspective of **Party 3**:

- **Party 1** is a **???**
- **Party 2** is a client

What is Party 1 to Party 3? Is there an accepted word like "superclient" that Party 3 can use to refer to Party 1?

Comment: My belief is that Party 3 would refer to Party 2 as "the main contractor" and Party 1 as "the client". Party 3 would need, or at least prefer, to know that Party 2 was not the person or organisation driving the project and would have a different relationship with and attitude to Party 2 that to a client who owned the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of building work, Party 1 might be called the "property owner". In other contexts they might be called the "end customer".

Additionally, and again in a construction context, Party 2 is (at least in the US) called the "general contractor". Outside the construction field, they can be called the "primary contractor".